# Could the new .NET runtime throw more meaningful null reference exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, runtime, c#-6.0

We know that the .NET runtime isn't very helpful when throwing exceptions as it shows only generic messages without indication to any variable or parameter names. But could it do it differently?

For example in this case:

```
class foo
{
    public void bar() {}
}

foo f = null;
f.var(); // NullReferenceException
```

but since C# 6 the compiler is able to produce a different code if we use the new `?` operator so it is able to check if `f` is null;

```
f?.var();
```

Couldn't it also wrap the call with a similar null check like when using the `?` and get the name of the `f` and create an exeption message like

> Additional information: Object reference "f of type Foo" not set to an instance of an object.

Would it be possible to use it also for other exeption types and put meaningful information there or is it *too* expensive whatever that means?

Comment: **"as it shows only generic messages without indication to any variable or parameter names"**. What about Stack trace? In my opinion, it lets you easily find a cause of a problem.

Comment: See my answer. Our grand children will probably not have that.

Comment: Actually, it's *very* helpful, since the call stack typically tells you exactly where the error occured. That's why solving a NullReferenceException is one of the easiest bugs to solve.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Stack trace requires pdb files and it's not always possible/wanted to ship them together with the application and without it exeptions are useless and look like this: `System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TestApp.Console.exe at Program.Main(...)` only with pdb-files you get the line numbers etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. If they could, they would have done it. Brad Adams [has blogged about it back in 2004](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/02/23/78341.aspx)

> The NullReferenceException occurs because an instruction like “call
>   [eax+44]” or “mov edx, [esi+24]” has resulted in an access violation. 
>   We don’t retain nearly enough information to form a correspondence
>   between a particular register being NULL at a particular EIP and the
>   fact that a particular reference in the application was null. 
>   Especially since the EIP might be in a shared helper like a write
>   barrier routine or an array helper.  In those cases, we would have to
>   perform a limited stack walk to get the effective EIP.
>
> The machinery that would be required to improve this error message is
>   huge.  For the foreseeable future, you will have to rely on debuggers,
>   or on FX code explicitly checking and throwing an appropriate
>   NullArgumentException.

As you can see there is very little information available to give a meaningful error message and also creating a mechanism will take lot of effort. Unlikely you'll see this feature in .Net.

Answer (score 3):

Think of yourself trying to achieve such exceptions throughout your code. What you have to do is to null-check EVERY reference type variable before EVERY use and throw a meaningful exception containing the variable name if it is null.

So it is expensive and probably worthless since the exception details contain the exact line number if you have the PDB debug database next to your assembly.

Consider the following code block:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    object nullObject = null;
    string nullPointerAccess = nullObject.ToString();
}
```

The IL generated by the compiler for this code is as follows (I put comments next to the generated IL operations)

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       10 (0xa)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] object nullObject) // declare local variable. After this point, the variable has no name. It only has a position.
  IL_0000:  ldnull 
  IL_0001:  stloc.0 // read local variable at position 0 (formerly nullObject)
  IL_0002:  ldloc.0 // load the local variable at position 0 to the stack
  IL_0003:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString() // call ToString()
  IL_0008:  pop // pop (remove) the return value on top of the stack
  IL_0009:  ret // return
} // end of method Program::Main
```

You expect the compiler to keep the variable names in another stack parallel to the existing and to access that stack whenever a null pointer exception occurs which will also require to keep both stacks synchronized so that the runtime knows nullObject is being referenced, which I think is not in the master plan for any compiler and will not be for a long time.

First of all, this would double / triple the cpu cycles required to execute a program. Even DEBUG mode compilations would not do that.

I hope I could be helpful.